# Elasticsearch Range filter with year only

Tags: php, elasticsearch, elasticsearch-jdbc-river

I need to filter my data with year only using elastic search. I am using PHP to fetch and show the results. Here is my JSON Format data

```
 {    loc_cityname: "New York",
    location_countryname: "US",
    location_primary: "North America"
    admitted_date  : "1994-12-10"
 },
     {    loc_cityname: "New York",
    location_countryname: "US",
    location_primary: "North America"
    admitted_date  : "1995-12-10"
 },
```

I am using below codes to filter the values by year.

```
$options='{
    "query": {
        "range" : {
            "admitted_date" : {
                "gte" : 1994,
                "lte" : 2000
            }
        }
    }, 
    "aggs" : {
    "citycount" : {
        "cardinality" : {
            "field" : "loc_cityname",
            "precision_threshold": 100
    }
   }
  }
}';
```

How can i filter the results with year only. Please somebody help me to fix this.

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You simply need to add the [`format` parameter](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-range-query.html#_date_options) to your `range` query like this:

```
$options='{
    "query": {
        "range" : {
            "admitted_date" : {
                "gte" : 1994,
                "lte" : 2000,
                "format": "yyyy"         <--- add this line
            }
        }
    }, 
    "aggs" : {
    "citycount" : {
        "cardinality" : {
            "field" : "loc_cityname",
            "precision_threshold": 100
    }
   }
  }
}';
```

**UPDATE**
Note that the above solution only works for ES 1.5 and above. With previous versions of ES, you could use a `script` filter instead:

```
$options='{
  "query": {
    "filtered": {
      "filter": {
        "script": {
          "script": "(min..max).contains(doc.admitted_date.date.year)",
          "params": {
            "min": 1994,
            "max": 2000
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "aggs": {
    "citycount": {
      "cardinality": {
        "field": "loc_cityname",
        "precision_threshold": 100
      }
    }
  }
}';
```

In order to be able to run this `script` filter, you need to make sure that you have enabled scripting in `elasticsearch.yml`:

```
script.disable_dynamic: false
```

Comment: when i use the format it will show the below error `{
  "error" : "SearchPhaseExecutionException[Failed to execute phase [query], all shards failed; shardFailures {[8yzuferaQCS2E04V_ieNvQ][jdbc][0]: SearchParseException[[jdbc][0]: from[-1],size[-1]: Parse Failure [Failed to parse source.....
  "status" : 400
}`

Comment: What version of ES are you using?

Comment: i am using Elastic version 1.4.2

Comment: Oops, sorry, the `format` parameter has been added in 1.5. I'm updating my answer now with a backup solution.

Comment: is there any way to pass this via URL like  `http://localhost:9200/jdbc/_search?from=0&size=10`